# Why slice(-x,0) doesn't produce expected string

Tags: javascript, string, slice

If I have this:

```
console.log('12345'.slice(-3)); // I get '345'
```

but when I do:

```
console.log('12345'.slice(-3, 0)); // I get '' (empty string).
```

what is the reasoning behind this? It makes no sense to me. Is there a JS API that can wrap around strings like I expect here? (I was expecting '345' again.)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "wrap around". What did *you* expect as the result?

Comment: I was expecting '345' again. By wrapping around, I would think that `'12345'.slice(-3,2)` would produce `34512` or what not

Comment: To get '345' again while passing a second argument, you'd need to use `str.slice(-3, str.length)`. To rotate a string, you'll need to use `str.slice(n)+str.slice(0,n)`.

Answer (score 5):

The second parameter is the index where the substring to be extracted ends (exclusive). If that index is before (or equal to) the start index (the first parameter), the result is the empty string.

As [the docs say](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) about the second parameter:

> If `end` is positioned before or at `start` after normalization, nothing is extracted.

After normalization, `.slice(-3)` is equivalent to `.slice(2)`, and the second parameter defaults to the length of the string, so

```
.slice(-3)
// equivalent to
.slice(2)
```

is like

```
.slice(2, 5) // take the substring from index 2 to index 5
```

and *not*

```
.slice(2, 0)
```